# AWS Cognito - Validate bearer token

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

Is there any endpoint in AWS Cognito to validate the bearer token?

I am using cognito as my oauth provider and I am able to get the bearer token successfully with app client id and secret.

Now I have to make a call to cognito, to cross verify if it really generated this token and validate the authenticity of the token from my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cognito issues JWT tokens, so you must validate them via a library, which will download the token signing public key from Cognito's AWS endpoint.

Here is an API example in AWS, that validates access tokens using Node.js. A front end app could use similar validation for ID tokens:

- [JWT Validation Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L24)

If you have particular technology preferences, post back and I'll recommend a library.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Archer

Comment: I'm trying to verify tokens in Python. Can you recommend a library for that?

Comment: The [PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) library is one of the best known ones for python - see their [jwt.decode usage example](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#encoding-decoding-tokens-with-rs256-rsa).